# HiDPI screen problem in i3wm

Tags: display-resolution, i3-wm, hdpi

I have a screen of the following configuration

2880x1800     90.00*+

laptop spec
Asus vivobook s14 intel i5 12th gen, intel ires graphics, ubuntu 22.04LTS

Ubuntu on Wayland works fine with scaling set to 200% no screen tearing and all the text in a readable size

When I switched to i3wm all the text sizes is too small to read, so I tried the solution presented on the internet of creating a `~/.Xresource` file and adding the following configuration to that file

```
xXft.dpi: 192

! These might also be useful depending on your monitor and personal preference:
Xft.autohint: 0
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.rgba: rgbterm*faceName: monospace:pixelsize=44
```

and also added the following lines to `~/.profile`

```
export GDK_SCALE=2
export GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.5
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

after adding the above-mentioned change I logged out and logged in to the i3 but still no change

the only thing that seems to work is when I use the following command

```
xrandr --dpi 192
```

but that too only changes the bottom bar of i3's scaling no other change all the text still remains small and unreadable

Also, there is a problem of screen tearing in i3 I tried installing Compton but and running it with the solution provided [here](https://ivan.reallusiondesign.com/fix-i3wm-tearing-in-ubuntu/) the tearing issue got solved but the whole i3 lags and kind of become unresponsive

what should do next to resolve this issue? am I missing some steps in implementing the solution provided on the internet?

so to summarise my problem I want the solution to the following problem

1. scale everything to 200% in i3 (apps like chrome nautilus terminal etc)
2. remove the screen tearing issue which 'i don't face while running ubuntu in Wayland

Comment: For high res monitors, you may have more luck running sway on Wayland. Sway is designed to "be" like i3, but runs on Wayland, the modern framework that replaces Xorg and, among others, more properly supports high res displays.

Comment: before getting into sway i just wanted to know is sway similar to i3 I don't want to spend much time learning something completely new

Comment: That is a good consideration. Inform yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for solution first to scale just add below mentioned line to `~/.Xresources` if you don't have that file you can create one. The value is multiple of 96 so 240 is 2.5x

`Xft.dpi: 240`

Then add following line to `~/.profile` you might have to change the value according to your use

`export GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.85`

Then log out and login again if you are satisfied with your display then it's fine or you can edit the values mentioned above.

And one more thing I found that the text of the bookmark in Chrome and the file name font size in Nautilus were still very small. So for that you can use `lxappearance` and increase the font size to 11 which was 8 for me.

for installing lxappearance

`sudo apt install lxappearance`

Also a tip whenever you don't see any change after you edited some config file: first restart i3 (when you change the i3 config) by pressing $mod+shift+r, if you still don't see any change (when you change the `.profile` file) try logging out and logging in.