# HiDPI screen and full HD screen setup in i3wm sccaling?

Tags: display, display-resolution, i3-wm

My laptop(Asus Vivobook S14 intel i5 12th gen intel Xe graphics) screen reslution is 2880x1800(eDP-1) and external display @1280x1024_60.02*.
I was able to correcly scale my laptop screen by editing the `~/.Xresources` file with `Xft.dpi:    240` and appending `export GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.85` in the `~/.profile`  file with but that resulted in external monitor also to scale up and its very large

**What have I tried**

I scanned the net for solution they suggested to use the following command
`xrandr --dpi 240 --output eDP-1 --mode 2880x1800 --output HDMI-1  --scale 2x2 --pos 2880x0`
this resulted the both of screen to move up and the mouse pointer clicks with a offset in Y axis

[image: before ruunig the command mentioned above]
[image: after running the command]

As you can after applying the command the screen blacks out even though mouse goes in the black region but the whole screen shits up the same result even after `--panning` mentioned [here](https://blog.summercat.com/configuring-mixed-dpi-monitors-with-xrandr.html). Kindly suggest some solutions so that I scale my external monitor properly.

Comment: Ubuntu by default now runs in Wayland. `xrandr` is for Xorg.

Comment: And nothing else to add to what was already commented here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1433238/1210606

Comment: first of all the question is related to i3 which is based on X11 not wayland. kindly read the question carefully. as for the link you mentioned it ask about screen tearing and scaling in native screen which is the laptop screen which i already solved. this question is related to problems faced in sclaing external monitor ... so i suggest read the question carefully before commenting

Comment: And I suggest you reading what has been suggested before in your other question to which, again, nothing else to add.

Comment: the comment suggested sway and i want to stick with i3 cuz some of the things might not work with sway as mentioned by various threads and YT videos, therefore i am looking for solution in i3.